# Swift pass the value from main to another viewcontroller with storyboard segue

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, storyboard, segue

I am trying to implement when user click the `tableView` cell, that selected `cell` value need to `pass` detail `viewcontroller`. Here, the `transition` connection I made by `storyboard` (not programmatically) and present modally transition I used.

I would like to know how to do, so provide some example.

[image: present modally transition]

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

   // here I need implement get selected index path and passing values to another vc

}
```

Comment: Hello @matt you should read my questions completely first. I asked for Swift and present modally transition. Your duplication reference different transition also it's objective C. please remove your mark. It will help lot of developers like me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `preparefor(segue:)` as follows,

I'm assuming few thing

1. Your current view controller is showing a list of player.
2. You are showing a list of player.
3. Tapping a player you wanted to show the player details.
4. Your player details view controller name is `PlayerDetailsVC`.
5. You a array of `Players` model, which are you showing in the tableview.
6. From storyboard, your tableview selection mode is `single selection`.

Based on these assumption your code will be like following

```
 override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow{
        let selectedRow = indexPath.row
        let PlayerDetailsVC= segue.destination as! DetailViewController
        let member = "\(players[selectedRow].name ?? "")"
        PlayerDetailsVC.player = member
    }
}
```

In `DetailViewcontroller` need to do below

```
var player:String? //print it within viewdidload
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. please provide more detail code.@Ratul Sharker

Comment: Please check the answer, i've updated it.

Comment: I am getting error on DetailViewController.player = teams[indexPath.row]  Instance member 'player' cannot be used on type 'DetailViewController'. @Ratul Sharker

Comment: Pay a close attention, to the code, here i am using an instance of `DetailViewController` not the class directly itself.

Comment: Certainly! you can. You can instantiate the `DetailViewController` inject the `Player` model in it and then present the detail vc modally. But before doing that, please check your segue identifier and you are taking optional binding of the correct class. Another thing is to check, the detail vc in storyboard has the custom class set to `DetailViewController`.